# Связь объектов в большом parent-child дереве

Tags: django

Нужно, чтобы каждый объект хранил id всех своих предков (для каждого уровня своё поле), а каждый родитель - id всех своих детей (все в одном поле)

Вручную в форме модели администратор выбирает только самого ближайшего предка, остальная цепочка записывается самостоятельно

Как это лучше сделать?

P.S. Все объекты принадлежат к одной модели

Comment: *для каждого уровня своё поле* Реализуемо лишь в случае, когда макс. количество уровней фиксировано и известно. *каждый родитель - id всех своих детей* Только следующего уровня или всех уровней?

Comment: Макс. количество уровней будет фиксировано. От 20 до 30 примерно.

_Только следующего уровня или всех уровней?_ Всех уровней